# Parsing to create a date field in Tableau returning NULL for September dates

Tags: date, tableau-api, calculated-field

I was able to successfully parse some text into a date but then found that all of the Sept dates were returning `NULL`. Here is an example of the string I started with:

`Apr 02, 2011 at 8:15 am`

I used the following to create a date from it.

`date(str([Date]))` and the Sept dates return `NULL`

When I remove the `str()` the Sept dates return `#Error`

Any ideas on how to get the September dates to return properly? Here is an example of the exact record for one. `Sept 03, 2010 at 6:27 am` The only difference that I see is that September records use a four letter month abbreviation.

Comment: The last sentence in your question shows you probably answered your own question. Look up the DateParse function in the Tableau Help and Knowledge base. That can help if you have a format that doesn't change from row to row.

Comment: That was it thanks Alex!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an ideal world your ETL process cleans data.

But, if your Tableau source data is not enough cleaned, you can massage it with some [Tableau functions](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/online/mac/en-us/functions_functions_string.html). For your issue:

> ### REPLACE(string, substring, replacement)
>
> Searches string for substring and replaces it with replacement. If substring is not found, the string is not changed.

Some ideas:

```
date(replace(str([Date])), "Sept", "Sep" )
```

Comment: Thanks! This was just some one off nike+ data so i didn't take any time for cleansing. Is the issue that Tableau will not recognize Sept as September then?